# How to make a module dynamically loadable on Debian?

Tags: debian, command-line, apache-httpd

I'm applying an API from maxmind. They require an additional module for Apache. Now they recommend the command:

```
apxs -i -a -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lGeoIP -c mod_geoip.c
```

- `-I/usr/local/include` specifies wherethe GeoIP.h header file is installed
- `-L/usr/local/lib` specifies where the libGeoIP library is located

This doesn't look like Debian command, so I guess I will need to look for command that will include those files in the environment so I can run them on the localhost server.

An equivalent command on Debian would be appreciated.

Comment: There is already `libapache2-mod-geoip` in Debian which is basically this module. If you don't need another version or want to change anything you should probably use the provided debian package instead of compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

What this command does is compile the `mod_geoip` module and link it against the headers of the version of apache you're using.

If you're using the stock Debian package of Apache then you simply need to install the `apache-dev` package (you will of course also need `build-essential` if you don't have it already). You may need to adjust that command for paths that Debian uses (if they differ) but otherwise that command should work fine.